# Should my controller take the (res, req) params or already extracted params?

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, express

I wonder what way should I organize my routing in expressJS :

**Params parsing in Controller**

```
router.get('/users/:id', UserController.get);

class UserController {
  get(res, req) {
    var id = res.params.id;
    UserModel.get(id, function(user) {
      res.send(user);
    }
  }
}
```

**Params parsing in Route**

```
router.get('/users/:id', function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  UserController.get(id, function(user) {
    res.json(user);
  }
});

class UserController {
  get(id, fn) {
    UserModel.get(id, fn);
  }
}
```

I find the second version **Params parsing in Route**  easier for

- **unit test**
- In case of change in the URL params or request body

but most of the example I found use the first version, why ?

Comment: Dunno. IMO anything that can be done to decouple layers should be encouraged; it makes testing easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider a much larger, messier real world application, with route names that no longer match controller names etc., it might be beneficial to place the full routing table (all of the `router.xxx` calls) in one place, such as a `routes.js`. For a given url, this makes it much simpler for a new developer to figure out which code handles which url.

If you included all of the parameter parsing in your `routes.js`, it would become really messy and you'd likely lose some of the benefit of having collected all that into one file in the first place.

That said, there's no reason why you cant have the best of both worlds by separating the routing, the parameter parsing/response formatting, and the controller logic each into their own modules.